# Angular: Display Chinese und Japanese Signs too Slow

Tags: angular

We wrote an angular application with 15 different languages.
By changing the language from x to chinese/japanese and just to display the characters when the language is already changed the app is too slow and shows for one second the characters like shown in the image below.

[Image to show character display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htQoR.png)

Is there a possibility to make the display faster? To show the characters correct directly like for the other languages.

Comment: Do you use i18n, some 3rd party library or your custom approach? If you have performance issue with information you provide I can only advice to use common best practices like using `OnPush` change detection strategy, make smaller components...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.